# SQLYog convert DD/MM/YYYY field not working

Tags: datetime, sqlyog

I have a table with a column called 'Start_Date', in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

I want to convert this into a datetime within a query, and have been trying various methods without success.

I currently have...

*SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, start_date, 103) FROM product_backfile;*

...but get the error message...

*Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'start_date, 103)
FROM product_backfile LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1*

I should add that I've tried this too, with no luck...

*SELECT CONVERT(DATE, start_date, 103) FROM product_backfile;*

The full syntax I'm trying to implement is...

*CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(start_Date, '%Y-%m-%d'),'T', '00:00:00Z'), CHAR(93), ' TO ', CHAR(91), CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(End_Date, '%Y-%m-%d'),'T', '00:00:00Z')*

I've narrowed the problem down to the way in which the Start_Date and End_Date fields are being interpreted, and have previously got the full CONCAT string to work in MySQL Workbench...

I'm at the end of my tether...please help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question, after some more investigation....!  :)

*DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')*

Full syntax I was after...

*CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'),'T', '00:00:00Z')*